# Issue with unit testing of react component that uses "Material UI" using "Enzyme"

Tags: testing, karma-runner, material-ui, enzyme

I have created two components LoginView and Login Form. LoginView uses LoginForm component for rendering. I am writing test cases for LoginView and LoginForm separately. The issue is when I import the LoginView and LoginForm component in a single spec, it works fine. But as I am trying to import same either components it raises an error

> Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded.

The error says that

1. I might be using multiple copies of React, but I am using
   react@15.3.2 and material-ui@0.15.4
2. The use of 'ref', I have not used 'ref' but Material-ui uses ref for
   their component.

I am unable to solve issue, any help/ suggestions are appreciated.

> Node v6.6.0
>
> NPM 3.10.3

Files are:

LoginView:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatButton, Dialog } from 'material-ui';

import BaseComponent from './BaseComponent';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';

export default class LoginView extends BaseComponent {
 // statements

  render(
   <LoginForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}  loading={loading} />
    <br />
     <FlatButton
        secondary
        onClick = { this.navToRegister }
        label = {__('No Account? Create one.')}
       />
     <br />
      <FlatButton
        secondary
        onClick = { this.navToForgotPassword }
        label = {__('Forgot your password?')}
       />
     <br />
  )
}
```

LoginForm:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextField, RaisedButton } from 'material-ui';

export default class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  // Statements
    
 return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <TextField
          type = "text"
        />
        <br />
        <TextField
          type= "password"
        />
        <br />
        <RaisedButton
          type = "submit"
        />
      </form>
    );
}
```

Spec Files:

Login Form:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';

import LoginForm from '../../src/components/LoginForm';
import baseTheme from '../../src/style/muiThemes/neo';

describe('Login  ', () => {
  describe('LoginForm test case ', () => {
    const context = { muiTheme: getMuiTheme(baseTheme) };
    const email = 'test@mail.com';
    const pass = 'testPassword';

    let form = null;
    let textField = null;
    let emailInput = null;
    let passwordInput = null;
    let submitButton = null;
    let submitSpy = null;
    let wrapper = null;

    beforeEach(() => {
      submitSpy = chai.spy.on(LoginForm.prototype, 'handleSubmit');
      wrapper = mount(<LoginForm onSubmit={submitSpy} />, { context });
      form = wrapper.find('LoginForm');
      textField = wrapper.find('TextField');
      emailInput = textField.get(0);
      passwordInput = textField.get(1);
      submitButton = wrapper.find('button[type="submit"]');
    });
   
   // Some test scenarios
}
```

Login View:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';

import LoginView from '../../src/components/LoginView'; // Error while importing this file.
import baseTheme from '../../src/style/muiThemes/neo';


describe('LoginView test cases', () => {
  const context = { muiTheme: getMuiTheme(baseTheme) };
  let submitSpy = null;
  let wrapper = null;
  let loginForm = null;

  beforeEach(() => {
      submitSpy = chai.spy.on(LoginView.prototype, 'handleSubmit');
      wrapper = mount(<LoginView onSubmit={submitSpy} />, { context });
      loginForm = wrapper.find('LoginForm');
  });

  it('calls componentDidMount', () => {
    const spy = chai.spy.on(LoginView.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
    wrapper = mount(<LoginView />, { context });
    expect(spy).to.have.been.called.once;
  });

  it('Access the dom', () => {
    expect(loginForm).not.to.equal(undefined);
  });
});
```

Comment: Please post unit test files too. Maybe not related to the issue, but one thing I see is that extending React components directly is not a good practice (LoginView extends BaseComponent), use composition instead.

Comment: @Shota i have added the spec files. When I am trying to import component in LoginView will raise issue in LoginForm.
Thanks

Comment: am I wrong using mount, shallow or render?

Comment: Try shallow rendering instead of full dom rendering (mount)

Comment: Hey, It works. Thanks @Shota